# How do I get the sha256 of a Nuget package without downloading it?

Tags: nuget

I would like to use Curl to get the sha256 of a given Nuget package and version. I think this is part of the Nuget API these days, but what URL do I need to hit in order to get the hash?

Comment: See `packageHash` in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/api/catalog-resource

Comment: See also https://github.com/fsprojects/Paket/pull/25/commits/ee4e1913b5b56ae442dbff7b7f8f506c9ef55275

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the links, [Mauricio Scheffer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21239/mauricio-scheffer).

Here is the relevant snippet [from Paket](https://github.com/fsprojects/Paket/pull/25/commits/ee4e1913b5b56ae442dbff7b7f8f506c9ef55275):

```ml
open System.Net
open System.Xml.Linq

let getDetailsFromNuget name version =
  async {
    use wc = new WebClient()

    let! data =
      sprintf "https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Packages(Id='%s',Version='%s')" name version
      |> wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync
      |> Async.AwaitTask

    let data = XDocument.Parse data

    let getAttribute attribute =
      let rootNs = XName.Get("entry", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")

      let propertiesNs =
          XName.Get("properties", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata")

      let attributesNs attribute =
          XName.Get(attribute, "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices")

      let properties =
          rootNs
          |> data.Element
          |> fun entry -> entry.Element(propertiesNs)

      properties.Element(attributesNs attribute).Value

    let packageHash = getAttribute "PackageHash"
    let packageHashAlgorithm = getAttribute "PackageHashAlgorithm"

    return packageHash, packageHashAlgorithm
  }

getDetailsFromNuget "FSharp.Core" "4.3.2"
|> Async.RunSynchronously
|> printfn "%A"
```

Output:

> ("CR5/gOr3EXghLOih4N+l8rlM4n5V3Vniv8L8tAeft5+P2QPSpU4CHF0YoTCXUpqfKXRQpvPej70MjHpBfgXJDA==",
> "SHA512")

The `PackageHashAlgorithm` should be `"SHA256"` or `"SHA512"`.